# flash messages function with arrays not working

Tags: php, session-variables, flash-message

Trying to modify a flash message function, but it is not working whatsoever.  Is the `$_SESSION[$type][$name]` and so on format not acceptable?

```
function flash($type = '', $name = '', $message = '', $class = '', $dismiss = '' )
{
//We can only do something if name exists
if($name)
{   
    //No message, create it
    if($message && empty($_SESSION[$type][$name]))
    { 
        $_SESSION[$type][$name] = $message;
        $_SESSION[$type][$name][$class] = $class;
        $_SESSION[$type][$name][$dismiss] = $dismiss;
    }
    //Message exists, display it
    else if($_SESSION[$type][$name] && empty($message))
    {
        echo '<div class="'.$_SESSION[$type][$name][$class].'">'.$_SESSION[$type][$name].' '.$_SESSION[$type][$name][$dismiss].'</div>';
        unset($_SESSION[$type]);
    }
}
}
```

Usage would be :

```
// set a message
<?php flash( 'error', 'test', 'whats up?', 'info', 'TRUE' ); ?>

// display a message
<?php flash( 'test' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is you're overwriting the `$message` with an array here:

```
$_SESSION[$type][$name] = $message; // Sets the message
$_SESSION[$type][$name][$class] = $class; // Overwrites it with an array
```

All you'll need to do is save the message to the same array (and make sure the index you give it can never be the same as `$class` or `$dismiss`. So for example:

```
$_SESSION[$type][$name]['messagetext'] = $message;
```

Then, of course, update the display part of the code to use that index:

```
echo '<div class="'.$_SESSION[$type][$name][$class].'">'.$_SESSION[$type][$name]['messagetext'].' '.$_SESSION[$type][$name][$dismiss].'</div>';
```

EDIT: After the discussion in the comments, the final code could look like this provided there is only going to be one message per `$type` and `$name` combination:

```
function flash($type = '', $name = '', $message = '', $class = '', $dismiss = '' )
{
//We can only do something if name exists
if($type)
{   
    //No message, create it
    if($message && empty($_SESSION[$type][$name]))
    { 
        $_SESSION[$type][$name]['message'] = $message;
        $_SESSION[$type][$name]['class'] = $class;
        $_SESSION[$type][$name]['dismiss'] = $dismiss;
    }
    //Message exists, display it
    else if($_SESSION[$type] && empty($message))
    {
        foreach($_SESSION[$type] as $name=>$array) {
            echo '<div class="'.$_SESSION[$type][$name]['class'].'">'.$_SESSION[$type][$name]['message'].' '.$_SESSION[$type][$name]['dismiss'].'</div>';
        }
        unset($_SESSION[$type]);

    }
}
}
```

Usage would be:

```
// set a message
<?php flash( 'error', 'test', 'whats up?', 'info', 'TRUE' ); ?>

// display all $type= 'error' messages
<?php flash( 'error' ); ?>
```

Comment: $_SESSION[$type][$name][$message] = $message; doesn't change anything... the array is not being built for some reason.  The values coming in are what I am trying to add to the array then for display pull them out.  It makes more sense to store them as an array, but I can't get it working as is.

Comment: You can't use `$_SESSION[$type][$name][$message]` as in your `Message exists...` pass you don't know what `$message` is - that's why I'd set it to a hard-coded value (I chose 'messagetext' as I assumed it was unlikely to clash with `$class` or `$dismiss`).

Comment: Also I've just noticed your "Usage" edit - you'll need to pass `$type` and `$name` to the second call or else the check `$_SESSION[$type][$name]` will always fail.

Comment: All the variables can be anything which is why nothing is hardcoded... if it doesn't exist it is created (first part) and if it does then it is displayed and the entire session[type] is unset.  That is why nothing is hardcoded.

Comment: But you're not going to get the situation where you've called '<?php flash( 'error', 'test', 'whats up?', 'info', 'TRUE' ); ?> AND '<?php flash( 'error', 'test', 'whats up?', 'something', 'TRUE' ); ?>' are you? If not, you can hardcode the array indexes after `[$type][$name]` - that way you'll be able to retrieve them without having to go through the whole array trying to guess what's what...

Comment: Gotcha... makes sense now... <code>$_SESSION[$type][$name]['messagetext'] = $message;
            $_SESSION[$type][$name]['class'] = $class;
            $_SESSION[$type][$name]['dismiss'] = $dismiss; </code>works.